# 'float' object is not callable Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a script that allows me to change nulls value for the mean of a column squared.

**I'm getting this error message:**

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
  2 

  3 mean_standarderror = df["Standard Error"].mean()**2
```

----> 4 print(mean_standarderror)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

**Code:**

mean_standarderror = df["Standard Error"].mean()**2
print(mean_standarderror)

"Standard Error" is a column of float numbers.

[This is how my Dataframe looks like with the column "Standard Error" added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgaAP.png)

Also, tried running this and it is showing the same error:

print(5.5)

Could it be cause I'm running it on Jupyter Notebook?

Also, I'm new to this so... idk if this is enough to describe my problem. (this case got closed cause had missing information)

### Error:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

----> 1 print(5.5)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable.

**SOLUTION:**

like @user2357112 supports Monica said:

The problem was that I wrote "print=" somewhere in the code. Deleting "=" solved my problem in the entire code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error shown does not relate to the code you provide.

Comment: Sounds like you accidentally wrote `print=` instead of `print` somewhere.

Comment: the only "callable" indicator is the `()` after `mean`.  Take the parentheses out.

Comment: `.mean() **2` should work fine, are you sure that is the issue? @RufusVS

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a complete [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Since we don't see how these variables are populated and can't reproduce the traceback, it's hard to know exactly what's wrong

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica -- based on the code provided so far and that traceback this could only happen if `print` was accidentally [shadowed](https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-5806)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that was the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I didn't know mean was a callable, and that was the only thing I saw that looked like it would generate the message.  I see I was incorrect now because the problem is apparently solved.  The OP apparently redefined the `print` function.  That would do it.

Answer (score 2):

to get the mean value

```
mean_value=df['col'].mean() ** 2
```

To fill the null values with that mean value

```
df['col'].fillna(value=mean_value, inplace=True)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer the OP's question of why the TypeError

Comment: Hey Subbu, thanks for the help. I solves the task. But also would like why i can't print any float